# Python: How to get index from an Array of JSON?

Tags: python, json, for-loop, selenium-webdriver, python-requests

So, I was able to answer my question before on how to get the value of a JSON from an array of JSON. But now I'm trying to convert it in Python(for selenium).

Here is the Array of JSON:

```
[
    {
        "id": 3328367679,
        "inbox_id": 35584,
        "subject": "Open this message"
    },
    {
        "id": 3328364404,
        "inbox_id": 35584,
        "subject": "Another message"
    },
    {
        "id": 3328363502,
        "inbox_id": 35584,
        "subject": "Open this message"
    },
    {
        "id": 3328357254,
        "inbox_id": 35584,
        "subject": "Open this message"
    },
    {
      "id": 3328349654,
      "inbox_id": 35584,
      "subject": "Open this message"
    }
  ]
```

Below is my script, it's working in Cypress Javascript. This works by getting the index of JSON that gives the first same `"subject"` which is `"Open this message"` and then uses the same index to return the `"id"` which is `3328367679`

```
function getMessageID() {
        cy.request({
            url: Cypress.env('url'),
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Api-Token': Cypress.env('token'),
                'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
            },
        })
        .then((response) => {
            expect(response.status).to.eq(200)
            var messages = response.body
            var messageTitle = 'Open this message'
            for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++){
                if (messages[i].subject == messageTitle){
                    return messages[i].id
                    break;
                    }
            }
        })
    }
    getMessageID()
```

How do I convert this in Python? This is my current script and it's giving me value of `None` when I print it. I run the `get_id` in the feature file since they're connected:

```
def get_messages():
    url = "https://uri.io/api/accounts/fdsdfs/inboxes/dfsfds/messages/"
    headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        "Api-Token": "123345dsfgsdrgf3456dfg5634dfv5"
    }
    response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)
    return response.json()

@staticmethod
def get_id():
    messages = ClassName.get_messages()
    message_title = "Open this message"
    for item in messages:
        if item["subject"] == message_title:
            print("Message id is " + item["id"])
            return item["id"]
        break
```

Tried as well using `for loop` within a `for loop`:

```
def get_id():
    messages = ClassName.get_messages()
    message_title = "Open this message"
    for json_item in messages:
        for message_item in json_item:
            if message_item["subject"] == message_title:
                print("Message id is " + str(message_item["id"]))
            return message_item["id"]
        break
```

I was able to print a `subject` using this code. How do I use indexes in Python? `print(messages[0]["subject"])`

```
    @staticmethod
def get_id():
    messages = ClassName.get_messages()
    message_title = "Open this message"
    # print(messages)
    print(messages[0]["subject"])
    # for item in messages:
    #     if messages[item]["subject"] == message_title:
    #         print("Message id is " + messages[item]["id"])
    #         return messages[item]["id"]
    #     break
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you so much @pr1nc3 for helping me out! There was a problem with assigning the JSON value in the variable because of the `None` being returned. Not sure why we have `None` but I reconstructed the code and combined it into just 1 (thanks for this strategy @pr1nc3 :) ).

This is the working code

```
def get_id():
    url = "https://uri.io/api/accounts/fdsdfs/inboxes/dfsfds/messages/"
    headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        "Api-Token": "123345dsfgsdrgf3456dfg5634dfv5"
    }
    messages = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers).json()
    message_title = "Open this message"
    total_messages = len(messages)
    for i in range(total_messages):
        if messages[i]["subject"] == message_title:
            return messages[i]["id"]
            break
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem that will occur from what you have is the concatenation part. You can not concatenate a string to an int so inside your loop you should cast the id to string:

```
message_title = "Open this message"
for item in messages:
    if item["subject"] == message_title:
        print("Message id is " + str(item["id"]))
        return item["id"]
    break
```

Apart from that if the response is the same as the one you posted on the top of your example the `return response.json()` is not required, you can use it already as is so simply `return response`

You code for parsing in the end is working fine after those adjustments.

If that does not solve your issue print the `messages` variable inside the `get_id` function and update your question because the error is in the api-call or the formatted response and not in the parsing of it.

Comment: Could also use the lovely f-string
print(f"Message id is {item["id"]}")

Comment: Indeed, but like this:   `print(f"Message id is {item['id']}")` so double quotes don't conflict

Comment: Tried this one but still returning `None` :/ `print("Message id is " + str(item["id"]))`. Not sure if this is the problem `if item["subject"] == message_title:` since it's always returning `None`. How do we check an Array of JSON? For Javascript we have `messages[i].subject` where `i` is the index of the whole JSON, then we get the `subject` from that JSON. How about for Python?

Comment: If you simply print the response you receive how is it formatted? If the array you pasted as example looked like your response the code would be working, so i am assuming that your response is differently formatted or is not an array.

Comment: Currently it still returning None.   `Captured stdout:
      None`
It uses the same response from the example. :/ not sure how to index in Python. I also tried using `for loop within for loop` but I'm getting a different error `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: I updated the question with the for loop within a for loop. Thank you for being patient with this @pr1nc3

Comment: I was able to print a `subject` when I used this `messages[0]["subject"]`. How do I loop with JSON indexes?

Comment: If I put it like this `def get_id():
        messages = Mailtrap.get_messages()
        message_title = "QA HPT Organization ID - courses"
        # print(messages)
        # print(messages[0]["subject"])
        for item in messages:
            if messages[item]["subject"] == message_title:
                print("Message id is " + messages[item]["id"])
                return messages[item]["id"]
            break`

It's returning `if messages[item]["subject"] == message_title:
      TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict
`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252480/discussion-between-pr1nc3-and-faith-berroya).